# Handling TFS Branches and multiple folders for large solution ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, tfs, visual-studio-2015, iis-8, tfs-2015

We're running TFS 2015 and VS.NET 2015 for a large solution with an ASP.NET web app as the main project and several class library projects.

I'd like our team to start utilizing branches but the concept of branches being in separate folders is causing all sorts of issues with configuration.

Once the branch is completed the entire folder structure and web.config values, project references, reference paths etc are all now different, as the solution is being opened from a different folder than the main branch.

We use IIS virtual directories so that also doesn't work due to the new folder for the branch.

If I go ahead and make all of these manual changes to make our solution work from the new branch folder, then every time we do a forward integration from main->branch all of this config of course gets overwritten, and every developer on the team would need to redo this config

Surely there's a better method to handle branches for larger solutions which have a high level of config and customization, is there a way to keep a single physical folder and just specify which branch you want to work on?

Comment: Your project should not care about it's full absolute path, and everything within it should only care about it's location relative to its root (the branch root).  Nothing should change from that part down regardless of where you branch to.

Comment: Sorry but that's a useless and ridiculous comment, an enterprise app of this size will always have references to resources requiring a path at some point

Comment: No, it does not.  You are creating problems for yourself and just saying "that's the way it has to be", but it's not.  You may have to rethink some things, but it can be done for a project of any size.  The fact is, you are following poor process, and then complaining when tools designed for good process can't deal with it.

Comment: Then I guess you should tell Microsoft that it's 'poor process' for an IIS virtual directory to require a path which changes on the web project for each branch, these aren't problems with 'my' app these are problems within the tools they built for us devs, instead of pointing fingers why don't you provide some useful input an answer the question, how do you handle branches in multiple folders, there's no possible way you just copy a website solution with 13 projects, multiple integration points & configs to a new folder and everything 'just works' with zero tweaking

Comment: @n4esa I agree with Erik. There's no need to be so combative, either.

Comment: @n4esa - as the age old saying goes, with great power comes great responsibility.  You can use Virtual Directories in ways that help you or hinder you.  You're doing the latter.  Virtual directories were created decades ago, long before CI or real automation were even a thing.  That's why there are automation tools for administrating your websites (creating sites, virtual folders, applications, etc...).

Comment: @n4esa - you may want to read this series, it's a bit old but the concepts hold up https://www.troyhunt.com/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity/

Comment: It's not combative, but trolling posts just to say 'youre doing it wrong' isn't constructive. With 100k+ lines of code I can't sit and justify every feature we've built and why a virtual directory is required, that was just 1 basic example to illustrate my point. If virtual directories aren't supported in branching, where is that documented? After 20 years of MS development this is what I run into continuously, here's a million powerful features, you guys figure it out, no best practices documented. So we come here for help and get ur an idiot comments cause you've figured out an alternative

Answer (score 0):

Don't use long term branches.  After moving from using long-term branches to a single main branch four all our teams I would never go back.  The merges were always terrible, even for seemingly simple changes.

We now use Release Readiness analysis to allow multiple developers to work in parallel on different features.  Check it out -

https://dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/16/are-you-release-ready/